# Truncate lines starting with a specific string

Tags: bash, sed

In a log file, I would like to truncate all the lines that start with the pattern "  IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE" to 40 characters. How can I do that?

For example, if file.log contains the line:

```
  IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE A.B.C          12345
                                       ^ 40th character
```

then I would like to keep:

```
  IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE A.B.C
```

I absolutely need to keep the name of the table (A.B.C in my example).

With sed I can remove what follows the pattern, but I cannot keep the other characters:

```
sed 's/  IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE.*/  IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE/g' file.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed, using backreference:

```
sed '/^\s*IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE/s/^\(.\{40\}\).*/\1/' file
```

- `/^\s*IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE/`: when line starts with zero or more whitespace followed by `IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE`
- `s/^\(.\{40\}\).*/\1/`: 40 first characters are captured and output with `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '/  IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE/{print substr($0,1,40)}' file
  IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE A.B.C
```

That will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX system and if your text can contain regexp metacharacters it's easily tweaked to use a string function instead of regexp:

```
$ awk 'index($0,"  IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE")==1{print substr($0,1,40)}' file
  IMPRESSION DE LA TABLE A.B.C
```